# Azure Project Publish Profile Corrupt After Uploading to VSO

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops, azure-cloud-services

When we create a **Publish Profile** (`azurepubxml`) for our **Azure Projects** (*ccproj*) and commit to VSO, we tend to get this error in VSO when viewing the file:

#### VSO Error when Viewing in Browser

> This file contains non-printable characters and no other viewer was found for file extension "azurePubxml".
>
> Click to download file to your computer.

#### Viewing AzurePubXML withinin VSO

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further review - there seems to be something in the TFS/VS IDE Tooling that corrupts the file during upload.

The fix is to perform the following steps:

1. **Download the original publish profile** locally
2. **Delete the publish profile** from VSO
3. **Upload the downloaded file** directly using VSO in the browser.

Not sure why this is occurring, but hopefully this helps someone else and short circuit time to resolve.